# Broadcast operation on array of smaller size

Tags: python, performance, numpy, array-broadcasting

I need to improve the performance of an operation performed on arrays of different shapes/sizes. The array `pos` has a shape of `(2, 500)` and the `xa, xb, ya, yb` arrays have shapes of `(30,)`.

The operation shown in the [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) below combines each of the two dimensions of `pos` with `xa, xb` and `ya, yb`.

Can this be done applying `numpy` broadcasting?

```
import numpy as np

# Some random data
N = 30
xa, xb = np.random.uniform(0., 1., N), np.random.uniform(0., 1., N)
ya, yb = np.random.uniform(0., 1., N), np.random.uniform(0., 1., N)

# Grid
M = 500
ext = [xa.min(), xa.max(), ya.min(), ya.max()]
x, y = np.mgrid[ext[0]:ext[1]:complex(0, M), ext[2]:ext[3]:complex(0, M)]
pos = np.vstack([x.ravel(), y.ravel()])

# Apply broadcasting on the operation performed by this 'for' block?
vals = []
for p in zip(*pos):
    vals.append(np.sum(np.exp(-0.5 * (
        ((p[0] - xa) / xb)**2 + ((p[1] - ya) / yb)**2)) / (xb * yb)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use np.tile
and modify the for loop as follows

```
xa_tiled = np.tile(xa, (pos.shape[1],1))
xb_tiled = np.tile(xb, (pos.shape[1],1))
ya_tiled = np.tile(ya, (pos.shape[1],1))
yb_tiled = np.tile(yb, (pos.shape[1],1))

vals_ = np.exp(-0.5 * (
         ((pos[0].reshape(pos.shape[1],1) - xa_tiled) / xb_tiled)**2 + ((pos[1].reshape(pos.shape[1],1) - ya_tiled) / yb_tiled)**2)) / (xb_tiled * yb_tiled)
vals_ = vals_.sum(axis=1)
```

Explanation:

1. In each iteration you are taking pos[0][i] and pos[1][i] and doing operation on xa, xb, ya, yb.
2. Tile replicates all 4 of this 250000 times which is the shape[1] of pos or the number of iterations.
3. We also need to reshape pos[0] and pos[1] and just make them 2D for operations to be valid.

Timing details:
On my machine vectorized code takes ~ .20 sec whereas non-vectorized code takes around 3 sec. Below is the code to reproduce:

```
import numpy as np
import time

# Some random data
N = 30
xa, xb = np.random.uniform(0., 1., N), np.random.uniform(0., 1., N)
ya, yb = np.random.uniform(0., 1., N), np.random.uniform(0., 1., N)

# Grid
M = 500
ext = [xa.min(), xa.max(), ya.min(), ya.max()]
x, y = np.mgrid[ext[0]:ext[1]:complex(0, M), ext[2]:ext[3]:complex(0, M)]
pos = np.vstack([x.ravel(), y.ravel()])

# Apply broadcasting on the operation performed by this 'for' block?

start = time.time()
for i in range(10):
    vals = []
    for p in zip(*pos):
        vals.append(np.sum(np.exp(-0.5 * (
            ((p[0] - xa) / xb)**2 + ((p[1] - ya) / yb)**2)) / (xb * yb)))
stop = time.time()
print( (stop-start)/10)        

start = time.time()

for i in range(10):
    xa_tiled = np.tile(xa, (pos.shape[1],1))
    xb_tiled = np.tile(xb, (pos.shape[1],1))
    ya_tiled = np.tile(ya, (pos.shape[1],1))
    yb_tiled = np.tile(yb, (pos.shape[1],1))

    vals_ = np.exp(-0.5 * (
            ((pos[0,:].reshape(pos.shape[1],1) - xa_tiled) / xb_tiled)**2 + ((pos[1].reshape(pos.shape[1],1) - ya_tiled) / yb_tiled)**2)) / (xb_tiled * yb_tiled)
    vals_ = vals_.sum(axis=1)
stop = time.time()
print( (stop-start)/10)        

print(np.allclose(vals_, np.array(vals))==True)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but have you timed this approach? It seems to be quite slower than mine.

Comment: Let me check that it seemed faster to me. Brb

Comment: @Gabriel Updated the timing details

Comment: Checked again, in my system it's not 10X faster as you what find, but it is 2X faster at least (not sure why I was getting slower timings before) Thank you Umang!

Comment: :) Feel free to accept the answer if it answers your query. Its a good motivation for me :)

Comment: Of course, I'll just wait a couple of hours to see if any other answer comes along. If not, I'll accept yours.

Comment: I'm finding that this approach throws a `MemoryError` for somewhat large data arrays (large `N`).  The other approach, although slower, does not have this issue. Could you confirm this?

Comment: @Gabriel yes that would be the case as np.tile will end up creating a big array and I think that might also be the reason for your slowdown. If you are really low on memory, your approach is better But for the current value of N(500), the code did not take much ram for me (<500MB)